Querying different data with different conditions
I have different types of documents indexed in my elastcsearch db. Each type is a table from my mysql database. We have a setup to index these table data into elastic db. I have project_id as a column in all tables, except one table which named 'products'. Only in 'products' table i have 'project_ids' column which stores multiple project id in comma separated values.
Now when i search, i also pass multiple project IDs as input. For all other tables (indexed data) the search should return when their 'project_id' column matches any of the project id am passing in my input. Only from 'products' type of indexed data, the search should return them only if all passed project ids are present in the comma separated value.
For example...
if project_ids column data is '1,4,5' then a search of (arrays) '1,5' or '1' or '1,4', etc should return this product data. But search of '1,7' or '4,6' should not return any data.
In the same case from other type of indexed data for a search of '1,5 (as array)' it should return all data that has column 'project_id' with any of the passed value. if the project id is 1 or 5 then the data should return. am using PHP.
Am trying setting up filter like this..
$terms_group = [];
                    
foreach ([ARRAY_OF_PROJECT_IDS] as $project_id_for_term) {
    $terms_group[] = [
        'term' => [
            'project_ids' => $project_id_for_term
        ]
    ];
}

$filter = [
    'bool' => [
        'minimum_should_match' => 1,
        'should' => [
            [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [
                            'terms' => [
                                'project_id' => [ARRAY_OF_PROJECT_IDS]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'must_not' => [
                        [
                            'terms' => [
                                'table_name.keyword' => ['products']
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'should' => [
            [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [
                            'terms' => [
                                'table_name' => ['products']
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'must_not' => [
                        [
                            'terms' => [
                                'table_name.keyword' => ['projects', 'city', 'states', 'parks', 'contracts', 'reports']
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'must' => $terms_group
                ]
            ]
        ]

    ]
];

But i see some of results like parks / contracts are not coming in result at all while i see city, states in the result. is there any issue with my query forming ?
